# My POST request fails in c# but works perfectly fine in POSTMAN

Tags: c#, post, postman, csrf

I make a login request to a nextcloud installation installed locally on my server. 
I pass 3 parameters: requesttoken, password, shareToken. The request works perfectly fine in postman but fails in my C# code.

I get the following reponse
with a 412 status code.

> "{\"message\":\"CSRF check failed\"}"

I copy pasted the c# code derived from my postman request which is like below. Any clues?

```
    var client = new RestClient("https://nextcloud.xxxx.org/index.php/s/Sryt58drbe34/authenticate/showShare");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("undefined", "requesttoken=oq%2Fqo4Nx0eNvYyty5QNeJqPbjZxMCtn3bFvUfEi%2Fwcg%3D%3AlOWrxPECsptWMBwGnTYMQ%2FG3yPENe7iQQwz7EQOLmYA%3D&password=bb9AYoqWSmAxiCgvFusW&sharingToken=Sryt58drbe34", ParameterType.RequestBody);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: What about cookies? Are there any?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark of fiddler.  Capture first request from postman and compare with first request from c# code.  Make c# request look like postman.  The default headers in the c# request are not the same as the default postman headers.

Comment: Are you putting the token in the x-www-form-urlencoded content type? If so you have to replace the "undefined" with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 0):

Your post should be something like this

```
var uri = "https://nextcloud.xxxx.org/index.php/s/Sryt58drbe34/authenticate/showShare"
var requestToken= "oq/qo4Nx0eNvYyty5QNeJqPbjZxMCtn3bFvUfEi/wcg=:lOWrxPECsptWMBwGnTYMQ/G3yPENe7iQQwz7EQOLmYA=";
var password = "bb9AYoqWSmAxiCgvFusW";
var shareToken = "Sryt58drbe34";

var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("requesttoken", requestToken), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password ),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sharetoken ", shareToken )
});

var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), formContent);
```